# Simple form inline input with check boxes

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form

My form currently has a form with field like this :

[image]

Simple form code being very simple for this one (using horizontal_form class) :

```
<%= f.input :taxes %>
```

However when entering data, most of the time people know their yearly tax, but rarely monthly as well. So I need some kind of different UX, than have them divide and remember all the time, this is what I came up with.

[image]

I'm not sure how to achieve this HTML with simple_form, but above screen is rendered from this HTML :

```
<div class="form-group row decimal optional calculator_taxes"><label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label control-label decimal optional" for="calculator_taxes">Taxes</label><div class="col-sm-5"><input class="form-control numeric decimal optional" type="number" step="any" value="0.0" name="calculator[taxes]" id="calculator_taxes"></div>
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
  <label class="form-check-label">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio1" value="Yearly">Yearly</label>
</div>
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
  <label class="form-check-label">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio2" value="option2">Monthly</label>
</div></div>
```

How does one add these 2 divs with radio `<div class="form-check form-check-inline">` to the existing input HTML with simple form?

Comment: Just wondering to know how this questions is related to ruby or even ruby on rails?

Comment: @KickButtowski I read the question as “how do I generate this HTML using ruby/[simple_form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/blob/master/README.md)

Comment: @KickButtowski it would be easy to solve this problem with HTML. I am using the simple_form in a ruby on rails view, completely different game

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're asking how to align all those elements in a straight line, in that case, you would just use `display: inline-block;` to the parent div containing all these elements. Or you could use flexbox to vertically and horizontally align them in a div

Comment: I am able to align them with HTML, I don't actually know how to do it with simple form